# Connection to remote PostgreSQL database stopped working with the timeout error

Tags: postgresql

**Update:** It works again without any timeout. Probably, the reason was that my VPS-server provider blocked some traffic or might be another issue. Again, I didn't change any setting.

---

I'm running remote PostgreSQL database on Ubuntu Server 22.04. Today I suddenly lost connection to it with the timeout error. Nothing was changed within the system.

**sudo -u postgres psql -c 'SHOW config_file'** command returns me a path ***/etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf***. Here I have the following line:

`listen_addresses = '*'`

In **pg_hba.conf** within the same directory I have the following lines:

`host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5`

`host    all             all             ::/0                    md5`

My firewall is inactive. Restarting the server doesn't help.

Everything works fine within the server. What could be the reason that I suddenly lost connection to my database from outside the server? I have tried accessing from different devices.

Comment: Might need a bit more info here, like  the connection string and some more detailed server config. If you're connecting based on i.p. address does the server have DHCP? If you're using a hostname, are you sure it's connecting to the correct machine? (maybe DNS is pointing you elsewhere).

Comment: I use static IP address of the server as a host and 5432 as a port. No DHCP. I've lost connection both in DBeaver and in my Python scripts. The last successfull connection was on Friday. And I didn't change any settings nor on the server-side, nor on a client-side.

Comment: Well, it works again without any timeout. Probably, the reason was that my VPS-server provider blocked some traffic or might be another issue. Again, I didn't change any setting.